# What are the white spots?

Tags: genetics, botany, plant-physiology, plant-anatomy

1. What are these white spots? It's like Braille writing or something.
2. How is the appearance encoded in the plant? (which I think is a Pine, though I am not sure).

[image]

Comment: If I manually made the "spot sequences" into binary strings, would it be possible to search them against some database? GenBank?

Comment: Questions should be asked in the question, not as a comment.

Comment: What do you want to know about the white spots? The name? Function? If possible please list the questions in a concise manner